# tooltip in Polymer is cut ourtside of the component it is in

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, web-component

I have made a web component "menu" and it has tooltips on hover. But the tooltips are not visible outside the component. As you can see below I've made tooltip with string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz". The tooltip is visible "inside" the component and not "on top" of it.

[image: visualization]

I want it to be visible on top of everything, not only my component.

If the code is any help, here's component:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tooltip/paper-tooltip.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">

<dom-module id="user-menu">
  <template>
    <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="user-photo" style="background-image:url('image.png');"></div>    
      <div id="user-name-div">placeholder1</div> 
      <div class="caption-inv">placeholder2</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
    <paper-menu>
      <paper-icon-item>
        <iron-icon id="right-menu-logout" icon="icons:exit-to-app" item-icon></iron-icon>
          <paper-tooltip for="right-menu-logout" position="top">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz</paper-tooltip>
          <span>Wyloguj</span>
        </paper-icon-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "user-menu",
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your "menu" component ?

Comment: I think this is a [clipping](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) issue. One of the containers has probably `overflow:hidden` set. The best way is to use ChromeDevTools to check the various containers (like the parent of `user-menu`)

Answer (score 4):

The tooltip anchors to the parent element; to remedy this I would move the paper-tooltip such that the user-menu element is its parent.

or simply add the attribute:

```
fit-to-visible-bounds="true"
```

Making it:

```
          <paper-tooltip for="right-menu-logout" position="top" fit-to-visible-bounds="true">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz</paper-tooltip>
```

Comment: the attribute helps me only partially, as some of the elements have only icon and are on 50px width element. tooltip with two sentences looks really bad. But I'll check switching the parent.

Comment: Did it work as you expected? Was this answer useful?

Comment: as I said - only partially, I'm writing my own element now. As I said, I have really small elements with really big tooltips, but there is no better answer so I'll mark it best